# T-Sql ordering results with count() by priority

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build a system, which has threads and posts. I am trying to fetch a thread that is the most popular (the user can click "like" button to make it more popular) and has most posts. The problem is to order the results by most posts..and then by liked posts.

So for example, if I have a thread with 300 posts, and 200 likes.. while another thread has got 300 likes and 201 likes..I want the second post to be selected..

Table structure in a nutshell:

```
topic:
--------
topic_id
liked

comment:
-------
comment_id
topic_id
```

Here is my stored procedure so far:

```
   dbo.Trends

AS
    SELECT TOP 1 title, COUNT(com.topic_id), COUNT(topc.user_id_liked) 
FROM comment AS com
INNER JOIN topic AS topc ON com.topic_id=topc.topic_id
GROUP BY com.topic_id, topc.user_id_liked,title
ORDER BY COUNT(com.topic_id), COUNT(topc.user_id_liked) DESC
```

I am not sure if I am right, or will I have to result to control flow logic. I placed the topic_id from the topic table before topic liked column in the order statement..hoping the selecting/ordering of the topic_id will take precendence.

**UPDATED: query updated.**

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd - You are right in assuming that `topic_id` will take precedence. A quick test would have told you that too :)

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010...I am building the stored procedures..I have no data in it.. vs2010 has sql express 2008 (built-in)

Comment: You can't build statements without eventually testing them for correctnes. You are going to get data so you might as well do that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know that you want. But maybe this will help:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(com.topic_id) OVER(PARTITION BY topc.liked) AS topicCount,
        COUNT(com.liked) OVER(PARTITION BY topc.topic_id) AS likedCount,
        title
    FROM 
        commnet AS com
        INNER JOIN topic AS topc 
            ON com.topic_id=topc.topic_id
)
SELECT TOP 1
    CTE.title,
    CTE.topicCount,
    CTE.likedCount
FROM
    CTE
ORDER BY
    topicCount,
    likedCount
```

**EDIT**

The differences between the `GROUP BY` and `PARTITION BY` is that `PARTITION BY` is an inline `GROUP BY` so this will not affect the number of rows. I like to use that in a CTE that is a inline view. Makes it clearer and you separate the different steps you want to do. If you remove the `TOP 1` you will see what I mean.

Comment: lol..that seems to be like my statment..I used group by,and you used partition by..whats the difference?

Comment: Updated the answer. I hope it answer you question